# Teensy as USB host

Tags: usb, teensy

Can Teensy 3.2 \ 3.1 be used as USB host device without additional shields in order to control some other USB device?

Comment: Which one? There are several *very* different versions.

Comment: I was thinking about Teensy 3.2 & 3.1 (will update my question with version).

Comment: Yes, but there are some issues with software support.  USB host on an MCU is always tricky, but devices that seem to work fine with the MKL25Z version of the Freescale libraries for some reason don't work with the MK20DX version - regardless if the hardware is teensy or custom.

Answer (score 1):

Check out which IC your board is featuring, then refer to [this page](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/datasheets.html) and download the corresponding datasheet. If it mentions USB OTG or USB host, then the answer is *yes*, otherwise *no*.

It seems that Teensy 3.1 & 3.2 are based on MK20DX256, which does support OTG. Note that it is "full speed", meaning you're limited to 12Mbps and devices which require higher transfer rates may not work.